# Reflection on COM Interop objects

Tags: c#, .net, interop, outlook, com-interop

Trying to create a mapper for an Microsoft Office object to POCO's and found this

```
// doesn't work
// returns an empty array where o is a RCW on an office object
foreach(var pi in  o.GetType().GetProperties() ) 
    tgt.SetValue(rc, pi.GetValue(o, null));
```

so have to resort to this

```
foreach(var field in tgt.GetFields() ){
    var pv = o.InvokeMember(field.Name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, o, null);
    i.SetValue(rc, pv);
}
```

which works for now but wondering why the `RCW.GetProperties()` doesn't work here?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The other two answers as of this writing are correct, but they miss an important opportunity to explain how the late binding of a COM object looks in terms of the .NET type system.  *When you call `GetType` on the COM object, the return value is the `__ComObject` internal type, not the COM interface type that you normally work with when writing interop code.*  You can see this in the debugger, or with some code like `Console.WriteLine(o.GetType().Name);`.

The `__ComObject` type has no properties; that's why you get an empty array when you call `o.GetType().GetProperties()`.  (At least some things in life make sense!)

If you decompile the `InvokeMember` method, you'll find that it has special handling for COM objects, delegating the call to an internal native method.  For "regular" .NET objects, the method uses "regular" .NET reflection, retrieving the appropriate `MemberInfo` for the requested member, and invoking it.

You *can* use .NET reflection on the *interface* type.  For example, if you know that the object is an Excel `Worksheet`, you can use `typeof(Worksheet).GetProperties()`, and use the resulting `PropertyInfo` instances with your object.  If you don't know the type of the object at compile time, however, you need to call `GetType()`, as in your example code.  In that case, you're stuck with using `InvokeMember`.

Answer (score 4):

It is because the COM object is late bound.  The runtime does not know what methods/properties will be available on a COM object until they are accessed/invoked.

Here are some good articles on the subject:

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q302902

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10838/How-To-Get-Properties-and-Methods-in-Late-Binding

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify them by name using `Type.InvokeMember(propertyName, BindingFlags.GetProperty, binder, target, args)` because there's no way of knowing what properties a lately-bound object will have at compile-time. Instead, you need to perform that lookup at runtime, usually via string comparison.

`RCW.GetProperties()` would only work if you could determine the properties and their locations at compile-time.