# Looking for a way to dynamically change field names in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, propertygrid

I've got COM object attached to property grid.

```
Type typeObj = Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progIdService);
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeObj);
propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = obj;
```

Now I need some way to translate object fields into my language using some translator. I was trying to use wrapper around object but with COM object I have no `PropertyInfo`, I have only `PropertyDescription` so I'm still looking for all the possible variants of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is reuse the DynamicTypeDescriptor class described in my answer to this question here on SO: [PropertyGrid Browsable not found for entity framework created property, how to find it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422844/propertygrid-browsable-not-found-for-entity-framework-created-property-how-to-f)

like this:

```
DynamicTypeDescriptor dtp = new DynamicTypeDescriptor(typeObj);

// get current property definition and remove it
var current = dtp.Properties["ThePropertyToChange"];
dtp.RemoveProperty("ThePropertyToChange");

// add a new one, but change its display name
DynamicTypeDescriptor.DynamicProperty prop = new DynamicTypeDescriptor.DynamicProperty(dtp, current, obj);
prop.SetDisplayName("MyNewPropertyName");
dtp.AddProperty(prop);

propertyGrid1.SelectedObject = dtp.FromComponent(obj);
```

Comment: changed it to `DynamicTypeDescriptor dtp = new DynamicTypeDescriptor(typeObj, pd);` and `OriginalProperties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(obj);` and now it works great! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use reflection to get the property names, although I haven't tried with COM objects yet. Be sure to include the ***System.Reflection*** namespace, then you can use it like that:

```
var props = myComObject.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    MessageBox(prop.Name);
}
```

Comment: `.GetProperties()` is empty for COM object. As I said I can operate only with `PropertyDescription` ( `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(instance)` ) but still I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: You're right, that's because of the Late Binding. Please take a look at this post for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9735394/reflection-on-com-interop-objects

Comment: so I need another way.